# How to place buttons in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app where there will be a `tabsetPanel` with three tabs (tab1, tab2, and tab3). I will have two `actionButton`s that will apply to all of the tabs but I don't want the `actionButton` inside the tabs, I would like for them to be to the far right of the tabs so now matter what tab you are in, you can see the `actionButton`s always.  Here is some code for what I am talking about:

```
tabsetPanel(
        
        tabPanel(
           title = "Tab1"
        )

        tabPanel(
           title = "Tab2"
        )

        tabPanel(
           title = "Tab3"
        )
)
```

And so I want these two action buttons to the far right of the tabs but outside of the `tabsetPanel`.

```
actionButton('load_inputs', 'Load inputs')
actionButton('save_inputs', 'Save inputs')
```

It would be nice if there is a way to just within the `actionButton()` function specify where you want the buttons to appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the location of any element using CSS. You could add the style for each button by adding the attribute style: `actionButton(style= "...")`. Also you could create a .css file with your custom styles. But for this case you could just set style to a `div` where the buttons are.

Below it is a basic example of adding two buttons to the right corner of the `tabsetPanel`.

```R
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),
  div(style = "position:absolute;right:1em;", 
    actionButton('load_inputs', 'Load inputs'),
    actionButton('save_inputs', 'Save inputs')
  ),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Tab1", h2("Content 1")), 
    tabPanel("Tab2", h2("Content 2")), 
    tabPanel("Tab3", h2("Content 3"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!