# Adjust the position of actionButton widget in R shiny DT table

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

The given R shiny script creates a simple data table as in the snapshot with an actionButton in the center. I want to place the button a little below it's current position such that it is in perfect horizontal inline position to the search bar. Thanks and please help.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(rpivotTable)
library(bupaR)
ui <- basicPage(
h2("The mtcars data"),
column(5,offset = 5,actionButton("CR1_S1", "Button")),
dataTableOutput("mytable1")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(iris)
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Data Snapshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place buttons in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537917/how-to-place-buttons-in-shiny)

Comment: @RobertoMoratore, Very different question that one. here above all I need is to position the button a little below, I don't see a good css attribute there. Please help.

Comment: You cannot put a button inside the DT table.

Comment: @J0ki, Thanks for the reply, but atleast can't we shift the button down a bit?

Comment: I don't think so because a little below is the div of the DT table, maybe think to put it below the table.

Comment: @J0ki, please check the link here, if you can help me https://rstudio.github.io/DT/003-tabletools-buttons.html

Comment: Then u can put the button like this link but don't know how to add html to center it.

Comment: @J0ki, can you help me with the script, as I am not able to do it.

Comment: Use the example, quit your DT::datatable, and use only datatable(iris, ....) do the same that the example but change the button name to your s.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the button inside the datatable in this way:

```
ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  actionButton("CR1_S1", "Button"),
  DTOutput("mytable1")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris, callback = JS("$('div.button').append($('#CR1_S1'));"), 
              options = list(
                dom = '<"row"<"col-sm-4"l><"col-sm-4 text-center"<"button">><"col-sm-4"f>>tip'
              ))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This should have been an answer.